Should I use "export interface" or just "interface" with "declare module" when extending a third-party interface?
I'm trying to extend the Request and Response interfaces from Express to include my custom properties and methods. Here's what I wrote in my types.ts file:
declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  export interface Request {
    user?: string;
  }
  export interface Response {
    jsonStatus: (code: number) => Response;
  }
}

Should I use the "export" keyword here, and what difference does it make?
TypeScript isn't giving me any errors whether I include it or not. I took the syntax from this SO post, except that I'm using .ts instead of d.ts.

I generally don't know if in this case there is a difference. Just came here to say that express has special Request and Response empty interfaces to add custom variables to that you can use in your TS file. Use declare global and inside it in namespace Express extend the interfaces.

@RoyAvidan That works, but there's a problem. jsonStatus returns the same Response object, and if I try to chain something onto that object, IntelliSense only shows me the jsonStatus method. If use "declare module," it correctly shows all the non-custom properties/methods plus jsonStatus.
